# Using python to read an array from a JSON file

Tags: python, json

I have this JSON file:

```
[
{
id: "29",
name: "abc",
email: "def@school.edu",
data: "2016-05-03"
},
{
id: "17",
name: "ghi",
email: "jkl@school.edu",
data: "2016-05-12"
},
{
id: "12",
name: "qwe",
email: "cde@school.edu",
data: "2016-04-11"
}
]
```

I wrote this script:

```
with open('C:/Users/L30607/Desktop/FYP/FourthMay-AllStudents-stackoverflow.json') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
    json_data.close()
    pprint(d)
```

How do I parse the file and extract the array?

I want to get:

```
d = [{id: "29",name: "abc",email: "def@school.edu",data: "2016-05-03"},{id: "17",name: "ghi",email: "jkl@school.edu",data: "2016-05-12"},{id: "12",name: "qwe",email: "cde@school.edu",data: "2016-04-11"}]
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @AKS Yes. It says that in loads return _default_decoder.decode(s)

Comment: What are the problems you have? Your question lacks any error description and (apart from a few lines) the minimal example code. Also, have you tried just searching for examples online and adapting them?

Comment: Small suggestion: don't close files with `json_data.close()` when you are already inside the `with` block, as it already closes the file for you at the block ending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is not formatted properly. I put validated it in https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and it shows that your keys are not wrapped in quotes. This is what it should be:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":"29",
      "name":"abc",
      "email":"def@school.edu",
      "data":"2016-05-03"
   },
   {  
      "id":"17",
      "name":"ghi",
      "email":"jkl@school.edu",
      "data":"2016-05-12"
   },
   {  
      "id":"12",
      "name":"qwe",
      "email":"cde@school.edu",
      "data":"2016-04-11"
   }
]
```

I re-ran your code and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

This is the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/L30607/PycharmProjects/untitled1/333.py", line 36, in 
>       d = json.load(json_data)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\json__init__.py", line 291, in load
>   **kw)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\json__init__.py", line 339, in loads
>       return _default_decoder.decode(s)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
>       obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
>       obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
>   ValueError: Expecting property name: line 3 column 1 (char 4)

Comment: Please do not add errors in the answers section, instead, edit your question and include the error.

Answer (score 0):

Always validate your json from http://jsonlint.com/ if you get any errors. In your case you are not giving *Keys* as string.

Answer (score 0):

Your json should be like :

```
[{
    "id": "29",
    "name": "abc",
    "email": "def@school.edu",
    "data": "2016-05-03"
}, {
    "id": "17",
    "name": "ghi",
    "email": "jkl@school.edu",
    "data": "2016-05-12"
}, {
    "id": "12",
    "name": "qwe",
    "email": "cde@school.edu",
    "data": "2016-04-11"
}]
```

String should be inside quotes. Then only it becomes as valid JSON. 
You can validate your JSON : [Validate JSON](http://jsonlint.com/)